# How to normalize json from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this json file sample:

```
{"T1": [{"time":"2021-03-25T13:31:58+01:00","data":-1}],"T2": [{"time":"2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00","data":[23,35,54,44,55,44,33,44,55,66,88,65]}]}
```

and I am loading it like this:

```
import os 
import glob
import pandas  as pd
import json

path_to_json = 'dir/dir/data.json' 

df = pd.read_json(path_to_json, lines=True)

df
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

When I try to call `json_normalize` like `pd.json_normalize(df)` it doesn't work.
Any suggestions on how to normalize this json dataframe into T1_time, T1_data and so on would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what do you get with `json_normalize`? If you have many nested elements then it may need many `json_normalize()`. OR maybe it needs first to get dictionary from list .

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it is simpler to get first dictionary from list, convert to Series and concatenate

```
df1 = df['T1'].str[0].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('T1.')
df2 = df['T2'].str[0].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('T2.')

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

And the same using loop with column's names

```
dfs = [df[col].str[0].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f'{col}.') for col in df.columns]

new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

---

**EDIT:**

For more dictionares in list you can use `.explode()` to move values to separated rows.

```
df1 = df['T1'].explode().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('T1.')
df2 = df['T2'].explode().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('T2.')

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

```
dfs = [df[col].explode().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f'{col}.') for col in df.columns]

new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

But this will work if you will have the same number of dictionaries in `T1` and `T2`.  If one of them will have less dictionares then it may repeate dictionary in some rows.

---

Minimal working code.

I use `io.StrigIO()` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run it

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '{"T1": [{"time":"2021-03-25T13:31:58+01:00","data":-1},{"time":"1990-03-25T13:31:58+01:00","data":999}], "T2": [{"time":"2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00","data":[23,35,54,44,55,44,33,44,55,66,88,65]}, {"time":"2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00","data":[23]}]}'
df = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(data), lines=True)
print(df)

# ----------------

df1 = df['T1'].explode().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('T1.')
df2 = df['T2'].explode().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('T2.')
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(new_df.to_string())

# ----------------

dfs = [df[col].explode().apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f'{col}.') for col in df.columns]
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print(new_df.to_string())

# ----------------

df = df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
dfs = [df[col].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix(f'{col}.') for col in df.columns]
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print(new_df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
                                                  T1                                                 T2
0  [{'time': '2021-03-25T13:31:58+01:00', 'data':...  [{'time': '2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00', 'data':...

                     T1.time  T1.data                    T2.time                                           T2.data
0  2021-03-25T13:31:58+01:00       -1  2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00  [23, 35, 54, 44, 55, 44, 33, 44, 55, 66, 88, 65]
0  1990-03-25T13:31:58+01:00      999  2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00                                              [23]

                     T1.time  T1.data                    T2.time                                           T2.data
0  2021-03-25T13:31:58+01:00       -1  2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00  [23, 35, 54, 44, 55, 44, 33, 44, 55, 66, 88, 65]
0  1990-03-25T13:31:58+01:00      999  2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00                                              [23]
```

Comment: can you help me make this work if `T1` has multiple objects such as .str[0] to .str[20]?

Comment: you should show it in question at start :). It may need `.explode('T1')` to conver it to separated rows, like in other answer. But I would have to create example data and test it. And it would be good if in question you would add expected result for new data.

Comment: I added code with `.explode()` and with example data which have more dictionaries in list.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
import os 
import glob
import pandas  as pd
import json

path_to_json = 'dir/dir/data.json' 

df = pd.read_json(path_to_json, lines=True)
df=df.explode('T1').explode('T2')
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('T1')))
df=pd.concat([df,pd.json_normalize(df.pop('T2'))])
print(df)
'''
    time                        data
0   2021-03-25T13:31:58+01:00   -1
0   2021-03-25T13:17:02+01:00   [23, 35, 54, 44, 55, 44, 33, 44, 55, 66, 88, 65]

'''
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I didn't execute it but I get the idea, it seems like this should work as well.